# Use COUNT from joined table in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Given a table `collections`, and a table `books`, I need a query to fetch a single collection with all its books, but only if at least one of the books is `cover_image=1`.

What complicates things is the many-to-many relationship between `collections` and `books`. There is a third table `rel_collections_books`, which ties the two together. Any book can be a part of multiple different collections.

The query to fetch all books in a given collection is:

```
$id = 7; //the collection we want to fetch

SELECT b.*
FROM   books b
       LEFT JOIN rel_collections_books rel ON rel.book__id = b.id 
                                           AND rel.collection__id = '{$id}'
       LEFT JOIN collections c ON c.id = rel.collection__id
WHERE  c.id = '{$id}'
```

This works so far, but when I run the next query, it still produces a result, where it should return null instead:

```
//none of the books in the collection have cover_image=1, 
//so this query should produce nothing, but it does:

 SELECT b.*
    FROM   books b
           LEFT JOIN rel_collections_books rel ON rel.book__id = b.id 
                                               AND rel.collection__id = '{$id}'
           LEFT JOIN collections c ON c.id = rel.collection__id
    WHERE  c.id = '{$id}'
    AND EXISTS(
              SELECT NULL
              FROM   books b
                     LEFT JOIN rel_collections_books rel ON rel.book__id = b.id 
                                               AND rel.collection__id = '{$id}'
              WHERE  b.cover_image = '1'
              )
```

How can I do this, and/or is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result.)

Comment: Noted - good to know! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're selecting books from specific collection, therefore the `LEFT JOIN` doesn't make sense here. Also I don't like the same table aliases in the nested query, renaming them will make things clearer. I think this *should* work:

```
 SELECT b.*
    FROM books b
        INNER JOIN rel_collections_books rel ON rel.book__id = b.id 
    WHERE rel.collection__id = '{$id}'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM books b2
            INNER JOIN rel_collections_books rel2 ON rel2.book__id = b2.id 
        WHERE rel2.collection__id = c.id AND b2.cover_image = '1')
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with the suggestion from @GordonLinoff, thanks